# Stetho Chrome on Ubuntu does not allow inspect

Tags: android, adb, stetho

I configured my app to use Stetho. When I run the app and chrome://inspect, I can see the device. However, there is no button for any Android device to inspect the network, sqlite, etc.

I am developing on Ubuntu 15.10. Does Android Studio, ADB or Ubuntu need any further configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault. After rebooting Ubuntu, it now works.